# Static methods of Promise constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am inspecting the static methods of Promise constructor. When I console logging Promise constructor properties I see resolve and reject methods:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Promise))
// Array(7) [ "all", "race", "reject", "resolve", "prototype", "length", "name" ]
```

I wonder are these resolve and reject methods are the same methods that are used in executor as its parameters or these are separate different things:

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//   do something asynchronous which eventually calls either:
//
//   resolve(someValue); // fulfilled
//   or
//   reject("failure reason"); // rejected
});
```

Specification mentions Promise Resolve Functions and Promise.resolve ( x ) which is the %Promise_resolve% intrinsic object. Can someone tell me are these the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties you see in the output of `console.log()` are the [`.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [`.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) properties of the global JavaScript `Promise` object. You can think them as static class methods of the `Promise` class.

They are used to create new `Promise` objects that are already resolved/rejected:

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
console.log(await p1);
// 3
```

The `promise` and `reject` parameters you use in the call:

```
const myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if (rand() < 0.5) {
       resolve(3);
   } else {
       reject(new Error('not today'));
   }
});
```

are just function parameters. They can be named however you want; they are visible only in the executor function you pass as argument to the `Promise` constructor.

They are not linked or related in any with to `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()`.

The code above can also be written as:

```
const f1 = (resolve, reject) => {
   if (rand() < 0.5) {
       resolve(3);
   } else {
       reject(new Error('not today'));
   }
};

const myFirstPromise = new Promise(f1);
```

This way it is more clear that `resolve` and `reject` are not related to `myFirstPromise` or to any `Promise` in any way. They are just local variables of function `f1`.

Comment: That explains a lot. I was little confused as specs told

Comment: A promise resolve function is an anonymous built-in function that has [[Promise]] and [[AlreadyResolved]] internal slots.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.resolve` is a shortcut for "take a value or a promise and return it wrapped in a promise". `myPromise = Promise.resolve("myVal")` is a shorter way of

```
myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => resolve("myVal"))
```

Promise.reject does the same thing, only obviously rejects instead of resolving.